# How to limit the number of selected checkboxes in checklist in Dash(plotly)?

Tags: python, checkbox, plotly-dash

My question is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes) one that is how to limit selected number of checkboxes but I wanted this feature for the checklist in Dash provided by plotly. I have read the official [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/checklist) but can't find anything useful.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered a similar question for dropdowns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70045332/9098350). We can use the same approach here with some adjustments.

Both the [`dcc.Dropdown`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown) component and the [`dcc.Checklist`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/checklist) component have an `options` prop that allows setting whether each option is disabled or not.

We can use this by disabling all other options when your option limit has been reached.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input


default_options = [
    {"label": "A", "value": "A"},
    {"label": "B", "value": "B"},
    {"label": "C", "value": "C"},
    {"label": "D", "value": "D"},
    {"label": "E", "value": "E"},
    {"label": "F", "value": "F"},
]


app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Checklist(
            id="dropdown",
            options=default_options,
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("dropdown", "options"),
    Input("dropdown", "value"),
)
def update_multi_options(value):
    options = default_options
    if len(value) >= 3:
        options = [
            {
                "label": option["label"],
                "value": option["value"],
                "disabled": option["value"] not in value,
            }
            for option in options
        ]
    return options


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

The above example disables all other checkbox when 3 checkboxes have already been selected.

Comment: I was planning to do the same but I thought there might be some better internal way,
So I assume there isn't, so thanks a lot.